# Raising e to the power of both sides of an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a simple question: in differential equations, it has been common in several of my homework problems to raise a base $e$ to the power of both sides of an equation to get variables out of natural log functions.

My question is what happens if you have a zero term? For example:

$$
ln(x) + ln(y) = z
$$
is equivalent to
$$
e^{ln(x)} + e^{ln(y)} = e^z
$$

which simplifies to
$$
x + y = e^z
$$

But what happens if $y=1$?

$$
ln(x) + ln(1) = z
$$
$$
ln(x) + 0 = z
$$

At this point, if you removed zero from the equation and then raised both sides by $e$, you would get $x = e^z$ when it should be $x + 1 = e^z$. Thinking about it in this manner, one could claim the following:

$$
1 + 0 = 1
$$
$$
e^1 + e^0 = e^1
$$
$$
e + 1 = e
$$
$$
1 = 0
$$
Is there some rule that explains why this algebra breaks down, and when it is wrong to raise both sides of an equation by $e$? This thought experiment is obviously incorrect, but in my first example, it is incorrect if you **don't** include zero in your raising-by-e operation.

Comment: $e^z = e^{\ln(x) + 0} = e^{\ln(x)}\cdot e^0 = e^{\ln(x)}\cdot 1 = x\cdot 1 $, not $x+1$ ...

Comment: If $\ln(x)+\ln(y)=z\implies e^{\ln(x)+\ln(y)}=e^z\implies e^{\ln(xy)}=e^z\implies xy=e^z$

Comment: It does not hold that $a+b=c \Longleftrightarrow \exp(a) + \exp(b) = \exp(c)$

What *does* hold is that  $a+b=c \Longleftrightarrow\exp(a+b) = \exp(c)$ since $\exp$ is injective. 

This is what is likely going on in your homework problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there's an algebra error: When you raise $\ln(x) + \ln(1) = z$ into the exponent, you should have $x$ *times* $1 = z$, not $x+1 = z$.

That out of the way, this is actually an interesting question and I think it's worth thinking about a little more carefully. What does it mean when we "do the same thing to both sides"? It means this:

> **If** the first equation is true, then the second equation **must** be true.

So, for instance, if $x+1=z$, then $x = z-1$. In other words, if there *are* numbers $x$ and $z$ such that the first equation is true, then the *same* numbers work for the second equation.

To your question, then --- If two numbers are equal, then raising $e$ to those numbers will produce equal numbers.

However, we must be careful, because sometimes "doing the same thing to both sides" actually loses information. For instance, consider the equation $x^2 = 1$. What happens when we take the logarithm of both sides? $2\ln(x) = \ln(1) = 0$. So we conclude that $\ln(x) = 0$, i.e., $x=1$, right? Uh-oh, what about the other solution, $x=-1$?

Problem: we have *lost information* in taking the logarithm. That is, in taking a logarithm, we have *introduced the additional assumption* that the argument of the logarithm is positive. So the instant where we lost information was when we went from $\ln(x^2)$ to $2\ln(x)$.

Since we can put any number into the exponential function and it is injective, we lose no information in "exponenting" both sides of an equation. However, in other situations -- such as taking the logarithm of both sides, or taking the square root of both sides, of on equation -- it is worth double-checking that you're not accidentally losing any solutions.